# Server Response Slowdown with php read_file MP3

Tags: php, audio, download

I have a project for a user that has a gallery of uploaded mp3 files that are stored outside of the httpdocs file tree and are being accessed via a php readfile() function.
The function works, but the page itself is impossibly slow to load.

I have a php file that is being called as the src for each audio file which I have used in several applications.

```
$sql='SELECT `name`,`file`, `filetype`,`access` FROM `'.$DBtable.'` WHERE `id`="'.intval($_GET['file']).'";';
$database->setQuery($sql);
$file=$database->loadObject();
//Check access against my access only if the file is restricted
if($file->access>0)
{
$access=isAuth($database);
    if($access<$file->access)
        {
        die('Restricted Access');
        }
}
    $uploaddir=BASE_URI;
$filename=$file->file;
    switch ($file->filetype) { 
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break; 
  //case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break; 
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break; 
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break; 
  case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break; 
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break; 
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break; 
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break; 
  case "jpeg": 
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  case "mp3": $ctype="audio/mpeg";break;
  case "ogg": $ctype="audio/ogg"; break; 
  default: $ctype="application/force-download"; 
} 
header('Content-type: '.$ctype);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file->name.'.'.$file->filetype.'"');
readfile($uploaddir.$filename);
```

The page itself is calling

```
<img data-src="file.php?source=images&file=668" class="thumbnail" parent="667">
<audio class="gallery_audio" controls="controlls">
<source src="audio_file.php?file=123" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="audio_file.php?file=124" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

where file.php and audio_file.php are copies of the file loading php code.
I have tried creating multiple copies of these files to spread out  the http requests, thinking that maybe the server was being overloaded by repeated requests for the same file, *there are only 10, but still no love. Also it does appear that FF consistently handles this better than IE or Chrome.
When I am only loading images, it seems to respond better even for much larger quantities of requests. These are very small audio files. 50-90KB so size should not be major issue.

Is there a better direction to be headed for audio files? Lazy load helps with the images, but does not seem to help much with the audio.

Comment: how big are the files you are trying to download?

Comment: the mp3 files are around 70-90Kb.. the ogg are a bit smaller... However the odd thing I have run into is that if I remove the audio files from the page and replace them with jpg, it loads more quickly, even if the jpg files are larger...It seems to be something to do with the html5 audio tag, or the php readfile() function for mp3 files

Comment: i would exclude mp3 files, you can try using microtime() to clock readfile execution and exclude that as the cause, then eventually work on the audio tag.

Comment: Sadly having mp3 files that the client can upload via a web interface available for public download is part of the spec for this project. I will try the microtime() debugging to see if there is some problem with readfile-ing that type of file.